# Conditional formatting also applied to spreadsheets not in range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

**Introduction of what it should do:**

I would like conditional formatting of value E in a spreadsheet if 2 conditions are met.

Term 1: The name of the worksheet gives the spreadsheet a classification which can be found in  spreadsheet "macro" in Range C11-F100:

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ODO.png)]

If the spreadsheet name is not in the table that no formatting should be performed on that spreadsheet.
If the spreadsheet name is in the table than is should look in which column it is for the class (A, B, C or D)

Than it should loop through the rows in that spreadsheet (starting row 2). If column G is "settle_plate", "active_plate" or "rodac_plate" is should check if value of column E is higher then Alert of Action limit in the row that corresponds with it spreadsheets classication fo term 1. If it is it should turn either orange or red.

[image]

**Problem:**
I only put in "settle_plate" so far (not "active_plate" and "rodac_plate") to see if it works so far. It applies the conditional formatting in the right way on the spreadsheets where it should do it. The only problem is that is also applies the conditional formatting on all other spreadsheets where it shouldn't do any condition formatting at all.
I now vloopup probably works better, but I am not familiar with that

```
 Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim macroSheet As Worksheet
    Dim macroRange As Range
    Dim macroCell As Range
    Dim useC5D5 As Boolean
    Dim useC6D6 As Boolean
    Dim useC7D7 As Boolean
    
    Set macroSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("macro")
    Set macroRange = macroSheet.Range("C11:C100")
    
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "macro" And ws.Name <> "blad1" Then
            ' Clear existing conditional formatting rules
            ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
            
            ' Check if the worksheet name matches the range C11:C100 in "macro" sheet
            useC5D5 = False
            For Each macroCell In macroRange
                If ws.Name = macroCell.Value Then
                    useC5D5 = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next macroCell
            
            ' If no match is found in C11:C100, check D11:D100
            If Not useC5D5 Then
                Set macroRange = macroSheet.Range("D11:D100")
                useC6D6 = False
                For Each macroCell In macroRange
                    If ws.Name = macroCell.Value Then
                        useC6D6 = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next macroCell
             
                ' If no match is found in D11:D100, check E11:E100
                If Not useC6D6 Then
                    Set macroRange = macroSheet.Range("E11:E100")
                    useC7D7 = False
                    For Each macroCell In macroRange
                        If ws.Name = macroCell.Value Then
                            useC7D7 = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next macroCell
                End If
            End If
            
            ' Find the last used row in column G
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Loop through each row in column G
            For rowNum = 2 To lastRow
                ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C4 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
                If LCase(ws.Cells(rowNum, "G").Value) = LCase("settle_plate") Then
                    If useC5D5 Then
                        If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C4").Value Then
                            ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                        End If
                    ElseIf useC6D6 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C5 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
                        If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C5").Value Then
                            ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                        End If
                    ElseIf useC7D7 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C6 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
                        If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C6").Value Then
                            ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                        End If
                    Else ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C7 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
                        If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C7").Value Then
                            ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                
                If useC5D5 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D4 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D4").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                ElseIf useC6D6 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D5 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D5").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                ElseIf useC7D7 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D6 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D6").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                Else ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D7 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D7").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                End If
            Next rowNum
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: Conditional formatting is an Excel feature that's available from the Ribbon's Home section. This is formatting from VBA.

Comment: Which worksheets should the formatting not applied to?

Comment: It should not apply the formatting if the name of the worksheet is not "classified", so (basically not in Range C11 tot F100 in the worksheet called "macro")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you left parts of an earlier version in your code.

After `For rowNum = 2 To lastRow` there is an branch: `If LCase(ws.Cells(rowNum, "G").Value) = LCase("settle_plate") Then` which contains a part starting with `If useC5D5 Then`. Now this part is (almost exactly repeated after the `End If` (the outermost one inside the loop): `If useC5D5 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D4 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color`.

There is a difference between them: the first one uses `>=`, the second one `>`.

The problem is that the second one is run for each worksheet independent of its name, and one of the formatting commands is always executed since all alternatives contain some formatting (painting to red).

Or maybe you want both parts, one for coloring things orange and the other one for coloring things red. In this case, move the second part inside the outer if:

```
        ' Loop through each row in column G
        For rowNum = 2 To lastRow
            ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C4 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
            If LCase(ws.Cells(rowNum, "G").Value) = LCase("settle_plate") Then
                If useC5D5 Then
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C4").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                    End If
                ElseIf useC6D6 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C5 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C5").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                    End If
                ElseIf useC7D7 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C6 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C6").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                    End If
                Else ' Settle_plate = True and Column E >= C7 each row (case-insensitive) - Orange color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value >= macroSheet.Range("C7").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange color
                    End If
                End If
                If useC5D5 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D4 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D4").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                ElseIf useC6D6 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D5 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D5").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                ElseIf useC7D7 Then ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D6 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D6").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                Else ' Settle_plate = True and Column E > D7 each row (case-insensitive) - Red color
                    If ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Value > macroSheet.Range("D7").Value Then
                        ws.Cells(rowNum, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next rowNum
```